# TextWatcher methods called multiple times

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, textwatcher, android-textwatcher, addtextchangedlistener

I have one edit text in Adapter , I have attached addTextChangedListener to it and all methods of it called multiple times , 
My output is like , If i suppose put Home output comes like H Ho Hom Home

Comment: Add you code in order to get help

Comment: You should add your textWatcher in `onCreateViewHolder()` method.

Comment: holder.etOther.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() { String ans="";@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
ans=arrayList.get(finalI1).getAnswer();}@Override
 public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {}@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
 arrayList.get(finalI1).setAnswer(ans+ ""+editable.toString());}});

Comment: holder.etOther.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() { String ans="";@Override public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) { ans=arrayList.get(finalI1).getAnswer();}@Override public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {}@Override public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) { arrayList.get(finalI1).setAnswer(ans+ ""+editable.toString());}});

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** Using timer to cancel processing while user is typing

You can try to add a Timer to process you text and cancel this processing while the user is typing.

```
private Timer timer;

myButton.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {  
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
        // user typed: start the timer
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // do your actual work here
            }
        }, 600); // 600ms delay before the timer executes the „run“ method from TimerTask
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        // nothing to do here
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        // user is typing: reset already started timer (if existing)
        if (timer != null) {
            timer.cancel();
        }
    }
});
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: I have Implemented afterTextChanged Method

Comment: holder.etOther.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() { String ans="";@Override public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) { ans=arrayList.get(finalI1).getAnswer();}@Override public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {}@Override public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) { arrayList.get(finalI1).setAnswer(ans+ ""+editable.toString());}});